# in android data/data/.....geting only half database

Tags: android, database, file

i have created database for android application and its size is 30 kb i have placed this database in to asset folder and used below code for paste it in to `data/data/........`
i am getting only 1/3 of my database after run on emulator. Is any one faced this problem earlier.

//enter code here

```
 private boolean checkDataBase() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        // database does't exist yet.
        Log.i("database", "NOT EXIST");
    }
    if (checkDB != null) {
        checkDB.close();
    }
    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

private void copyDataBase()  
{
    FileInputStream myInput = null;
    String outFileName;
    FileOutputStream myOutput = null;
        try{
        // Open your local db as the input stream
        //InputStream myInput = myContext.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.menu);
        myInput = (FileInputStream) myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        // Path to the just created empty db
        outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        // Open the empty db as the output stream
        myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        try{
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("catch ", "Ecxeption"+e.getMessage());
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }finally{
        try{
            // Close the streams
            myOutput.flush();
            myOutput.close();
            myInput.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e2) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }
}
```

when i am running this code in emulator then i found my database in to data/data/.......
but i found only 7 kb database.
please help me.

Comment: where you are calling this copyDataBase() method? I think on startActivity() you are calling right.

Comment: i am calling on onCreate() method initially i had check whether database exist or not if not then i copied.

Answer (score 0):

How about changing

```
      while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
      }
```

to

```
      while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
      }
```

I don't think the stream is done until it hits -1

Comment: thanks for reply but its also not working i got database size 0 on getting from data/data/packagename/databases/menu.db